# "I'm really enjoyed" Correct?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct "I'm really enjoyed..."? If it is not, can you please correct it?

I want to know why is it wrong, because someone told me, that's incorrect grammar but doesn't want to point it out.

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to explain what you are trying to convey. See [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct grammatically...but!

That's a most unusual statement. It is in the passive voice, which means that it is not you are doing the enjoying but somebody else - who is enjoying you.

If you wanted to say that you were enjoying something/someone, you would write:

> > I really enjoy....

or

> > I (have) really enjoyed...

What makes the statement so unusual is that we do not usually enjoy people (unless we are cannibals), we enjoy their company or conversation.

We generally enjoy objects and experiences. So, using the passive voice you might write:

> > Our visit to the theatre was really enjoyed.

But not:

> > My sister was really enjoyed

unless you are implying that someone had a good time at her expense.

Answer (score 0):

If you enjoy yourself you have a good time.

- Did you enjoy yourself at the beach? (Did you have a good time at the beach?)
- Yes I had a great time.

---

If you enjoy food or drink you find it tasty and like eating/drinking it.

- Did you enjoy your meal?  (Was your meal tasty?)
- Yes I really enjoyed it.  (I liked the meal a lot)

---

If you enjoy an activity you have fun.

- Did you enjoy running the marathon?  (Was running the marathon pleasurable?)
- No I didn't enjoy it. My feet were covered in blisters by the end.

---

**If you enjoy a person**, you have sex with them. (Archaic)

- Did you enjoy Sarah?  (Archaic - Did you have sex with Sarah?)
- Yes I enjoyed her.  (Archaic - Yes I had sex with her)

Note that this is very disrespectful to the person.

---

So maybe your friend was embarrassed to tell you what this can mean.

If **you are enjoyed** (by someone) then someone has sex with you.

It was originally used to describe a man having sex with a woman. The man was said to have enjoyed the woman. This does not mean that the man gave joy to the woman, it means that he enjoyed her as he might a enjoy a good meal.

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J2NHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA456&dq=%22he+enjoyed+her%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQvves6ZHhAhXMVBUIHfIMC_8Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22he%20enjoyed%20her%22&f=false

Comment: I've definitely heard *enjoyed* used about a person without any intention to convey that meaning, nor was it taken as meaning that by the audience.

Comment: @SamBC - Interesting. Could you give an example sentence?

Comment: Well, the obvious one is a performer - "I really enjoyed Eddie Izzard last night", but that's not the sort of thing we're talking about, obvs. In the present tense, I know it widely used to indicate that someone likes spending time with someone - "oh, good, I enjoy Lucy". But I've also - and less often - heard it used just for someone that time has been spent with, usually (if not universally, I'm not sure) when first meeting that person - "what did you think of the party?" "It was good, I enjoyed your friend John."

Comment: I should add that every recollection of this has been of people with a particular sort of RP-esque accent. Also that I am familiar with your sense of *enjoy* about a person in a sort of academic way, but never heard it used in practice, and I'm not sure most people I know would recognise that meaning at all. At least, not without some eyebrow waggling and elbow-nudging to drive it home.